# mysql cluster performance - single query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, cluster-computing

Will deploying a mysql cluster speed up a single join-query on a large set of data and multiple tables?

example query:

```
select k.something
from
kite k
join asd a on a.kite = k.id
join dbo.database2.asdff asdff on asdff.asd = a.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a cluster will increase your ability to run multiple queries at the same time, but will not speed up a single query and could in fact slow it down depending on your setup.